# How to fill cells with word and num cobinations acording function input?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a VBA function for excel that fill down cells according 4 variable; 2 of them text two of them numbers . For instance, When I enter formula with word1;num1;word2;num2 variables it should fill below cells of num1xnum2 with word1-1-word2-2 then get down cell and change its value to word1-1-word2-2..... until get word1-num1-word2-num2 . for cexmal if some one enter =myfunction(right;2;up,3) in B2 cell, acordingly B3 should filled with right-1-up-1,B4 should filled with right-1-up-2;B5 should filled with right-1-up-3,B6 should filled with right-2-up-1 ans so on until B9 should filled with right-2-up-3

My codes are below but it did not worked.

```
Function Myfunction(word1 As String, num1 As Double, word2 As String, num2 As Double) As String

Myrow = aplication.Caller.Row
Mycol = aplication.Caller.Column
For i = 1 To num1
    For j = 1 To num2
        Myrow = Myrow + 1
        Cells(Myrow, Mycol) = textjoin(word1 & "-" & i & word2 & "-" & j)
    Next j
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Are you calling this from a worksheet cell? User-defined functions called from a cell are meant to return value(s) to the calling cell,, not modify other cells.

Comment: @BigBen But VBA UDFs can spill, see below.

Comment: @jkpieterse which is why I said return value(s) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to have an array returned by the function like you'd get with them fancy newer formulas which have been added to Excel over the few recent years, it'd be done more like this:

```
Function Myfunction(word1 As String, num1 As Double, word2 As String, num2 As Double)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arr 'always declare all your variables
    ReDim arr(1 To num1 * num2, 1 To 1) 'array to return with the function
    For i = 1 To num1
        For j = 1 To num2
            arr((i - 1) * num2 + j, 1) = word1 & "-" & i & "-" & word2 & "-" & j
        Next j
    Next i
    Myfunction = arr 'return said array to your cell 
                     'which will spill to num1*num2 further than your original cell
End Function
```

**EDIT:**
This is to show it works with numbers just fine as well

[image]

Comment: when enter string in string inputs place(word1 and word2 it returns #value! error. And when enter numeric values in strings inputs it returns result word1-1-word2-1 to only function inputed cell  for example If =Myfunction(2;4;6;3) entered in c3 cell it returns 2-1-6-1 result in c3 cell it does not make any change in c4 c5 ...... and other cells.

Comment: I have no issues with numbers, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks; After trying in newer version of excel; it worked.

Comment: My bad, yeah, forgot it was from 365 that they've added the spill functionality :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Function Myfunction(word1 As String, num1 As Double, word2 As String, num2 As Double) As Variant
    Dim results() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim myRow As Long
    ReDim results(1 To num1 * num2, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To num1
        For j = 1 To num2
            myRow = myRow + 1
            results(myRow, 1) = word1 & "-" & i & word2 & "-" & j
        Next j
    Next i
    Myfunction = results()
End Function
```